# Store triple of string and two values

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am looking for a way to store the following datastructure

```
Name1 | 100 | 200 
Name2 | 99  | 2 
Name3 | 11  | 55
```

I know I could use a `dictionary object` with a `string array` as `TValue` or a `datatable` but the first is unhandy and the second is like use a shotgun to kill flies. I could write my own class for this but I just guess (because this is a high frequent structure) there must be a proper object but I cannot find it. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Try a [`Tuple<T1,T2,T3>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387150(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a variation of `Tuple` class. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

If your first column is an identifier, you can use a type

```
Dictionary(Of String, Tuple(Of Integer, Integer))
```

If your first column is a column that can have not unique values you can use a list and a Tuple with 3 parameters:

```
List(Of Tuple(Of String, Integer, Integer))
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is to store all three values as a single column in your database table perhaps serialize your own class into JSON or XML.  If you go with JSON you could then just store into a varchar column.  For XML you could store to varchar or xml (depending on database environment).

See http://james.newtonking.com/json for details on using JSON

[MSDN: Intro to XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Heres a codesample:

```
var sampleCollection = new List<Tuple<string, int, int>>();
sampleCollection.Add(new Tuple<string, int, int>("name1", 100, 200));
sampleCollection.Add(new Tuple<string, int, int>("name2", 99, 2));
sampleCollection.Add(new Tuple<string, int, int>("name3", 11, 55));
```